# can not rewrite url in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite "222" to "34" in wordpress.
I have added these lines to my function.php:

```
add_action( 'init', 'mydid_add_rewrite_rules' );    
function mydid_add_rewrite_rules() {  
   global $wp_rewrite;  
   add_rewrite_rule( '222', '34','top');    
   $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();
}
```

However, that doe not work. the link with "34" works, but with the "222" doe not.
I also checked with [monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer](http://wordpress.org/plugins/monkeyman-rewrite-analyzer/) and it seems that the rewrite rule is not inserted. Why? I AM flushing...

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Anyone? Please help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it.
It seems that the destination should be something that has a file.
When I change it to  add_rewrite_rule( '222', 'index.php\34','top');
It works.